# Windows phone local database - List as column

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone

I am developing an app for Windows phone 7.1 I have set up a class-child of DataContext, that has a table of my class called EventC.

And the class EventC is this:

```
[Table]
public class EventC
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int _id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string date { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [Column(DbType="NText")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int category { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public List<int> categories { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string image { get; set; }

}
```

On runtime I get the following error: "Unable to determine SQL type for System.Collections.Generic.List".

It's not possible to have a list as a column? What can I do instead?
Have seperate table for the categories-association?
Which types are supported?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably just to save your list in  a comma separated string:

```
    [Column]
    public string categoriesStr {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(",", categories);
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                categories = new List<int>();
            }
            else
            {
                categories = value.Split(',').Select((val) => int.Parse(val)).ToList();
            }
        } 
    }

    public List<int> categories { get; set; }
```